# Python PUT request to update nested JSON fails

Tags: python, json, api, http, python-requests

I'm trying a PUT request as shown below, but I keep getting a 500 Status code.

```
r=requests.put(url=<URL>, data = <JSON file>)
```

The data is a nested JSON file I created from an OrderdDict and then converted to JSON using json.dumps() command to convert Python boolean values to JSON boolean and looks like so:

`{"patient_name": "Walter Mitty", "preop_room": "PREOP-7", "or_room": "OR-4", "pacu_bed": "BED 2", "preop_checklist": [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false], "or_checklist": [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true], "pacu_checklist": [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false], "location": "OR Room"}`

I validated this JSON file and it is in the correct format. But I can't figure out why I keep getting a 500 Status code when I try the PUT request.

Comment: Would be helpful, if you can find any error message and post it here.

Comment: @Biswanath- The only output I get when I print r is this: <Response [500]>

Comment: 500 indicates a server-side error which could mean virtually anything. You need developer access to the server to debug this.

Comment: Please use print r.content.

Comment: don't you need any headers with `access token` or `client key` ?

Comment: @Biswanath- Thanks for that! I actually tried directly passing the OrderedDict and instead of using the 'data' parameter in the PUT request, I used the 'json' parameter and it successfully updated! Thanks again.

Comment: Also,generally bad json would result a bad request, with status code 4xx.

Comment: The error probably happened because the content type was not set to `application/json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to either use `request.put(url=<url>, json=<json-data>)` or you convert your dict explicetly to json using `json.dumps(<json-data>)` and then be able to deliver it using `data=<json-data>`.

And, depending on the implementation of the REST Api you're talking to, you may need to set the content-type header: `requests.put(url=<url>, json=<json-data>, headers={ 'content-type': 'application/json' })`

Comment: Thank you! The first method did work for me just fine and I was able to update the JSON file through the API. Thank you!